# Extraction of processes (process types) from table containing activities and their tasks

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table with working activities and their tasks:

```
TASK_ID | TASK_TYPE_ID | TASK_NAME | ACT_ID
========+==============+===========+========
100000  | 101          | A         | 300
100001  | 102          | B         | 300
100002  | 103          | C         | 300
100004  | 101          | A         | 310
100005  | 103          | C         | 310
100006  | 101          | A         | 312
100007  | 103          | C         | 312
100008  | 101          | A         | 314
100009  | 102          | B         | 314
```

One can see that in this table there are four activities (300,310,312,314) but three distinct process. Here it is assumed that process is distinct sequence of tasks. First process = A+B+C sequence (used in activity 300), and second process = A+C sequence (used in activities 310 and 312), and fourth process = A+B. There could also be other activities that have (use) the same process.

I need SQL which will extract all processes or process types (distinct task sequences) from such a table.

The resulting output should look like:

```
PROCESS | PROCESS_TASKS_SEQUENCE
========+=======================
1       | A,B,C
2       | A,C
3       | A,B
```

Three distinct processes extracted from input data, 1st process consists of tasks A+B+C, second one consists of tasks A+C and third one consists of tasks A+B.

Comment: can you add sample of result table that you expect to see? it's not clear now what are you going to achieve

Comment: are the processes defined elsewhere in a separate table?, or are you just after pulling out the different combinations of tasks per act_id?

Comment: Sequence of Task A+C is not as Task C+A, these two sequences are two different processes. Processes are not defined in separate table! Yes, give me the list of distinct combinations of tasks grouped over act_id (do not sort them with order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b108b/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( TASK_ID, TASK_TYPE_ID, TASK_NAME, ACT_ID ) AS
          SELECT 100000, 101, 'A', 300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100001, 102, 'B', 300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100002, 103, 'C', 300 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100004, 101, 'A', 310 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100005, 103, 'C', 310 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100006, 101, 'A', 312 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100007, 103, 'C', 312 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100008, 101, 'A', 314 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100009, 102, 'B', 314 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100010, 102, 'B', 316 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 100011, 101, 'A', 316 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS PROCESS,
       PROCESS_TASK_SEQUENCE
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         LISTAGG( TASK_NAME, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY TASK_ID ) AS PROCESS_TASK_SEQUENCE
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY ACT_ID
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b108b/1/0)**:

```
| PROCESS | PROCESS_TASK_SEQUENCE |
|---------|-----------------------|
|       1 |                 A,B,C |
|       2 |                   A,B |
|       3 |                   A,C |
|       4 |                   B,A |
```

Comment: Almost, since there's ORDER BY TASK_TYPE_ID this query will not differ Process1 with tasks A+B and Process2 with tasks B+A. Different sequence of the same tasks are different processes, I need unique sequences (not ordered tasks).

Comment: @sbrbot Updated - assuming `TASK_ID` is incremented sequentially then you can just change it to `ORDER BY TASK_ID`

Answer (score 0):

Is this anything like what you're after?

```
with sample_data as (select 100000 task_id, 101 task_type_id, 'Task A' task_name, 300 act_id from dual union all
                     select 100001 task_id, 102 task_type_id, 'Task B' task_name, 300 act_id from dual union all
                     select 100002 task_id, 103 task_type_id, 'Task C' task_name, 300 act_id from dual union all
                     select 100004 task_id, 101 task_type_id, 'Task A' task_name, 310 act_id from dual union all
                     select 100005 task_id, 103 task_type_id, 'Task C' task_name, 310 act_id from dual union all
                     select 100006 task_id, 101 task_type_id, 'Task A' task_name, 312 act_id from dual union all
                     select 100007 task_id, 103 task_type_id, 'Task C' task_name, 312 act_id from dual union all
                     select 100008 task_id, 101 task_type_id, 'Task A' task_name, 314 act_id from dual union all
                     select 100009 task_id, 102 task_type_id, 'Task B' task_name, 314 act_id from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called sample_data which contains ... sample data. See SQL below:
select distinct task_name,
                dense_rank() over (order by length(task_list) desc, task_list) grp_num
from   (select task_id,
               task_type_id,
               task_name,
               act_id,
               listagg(task_type_id, ',') within group (order by task_type_id) over (partition by act_id) task_list
        from   sample_data)
order by grp_num, task_name;


TASK_NAME    GRP_NUM
--------- ----------
Task A             1
Task B             1
Task C             1
Task A             2
Task B             2
Task A             3
Task C             3
```